# Want to design a promotion model in Django

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

1. Brand partner creates a plan
   a. Creates a plan in the database with planID, planName, amountOptions and
   tenureOptions, benefitPercentage (for example: 10), benefitType
   (cashback/extraVoucher) and any other attributes needed.
2. Brand partner creates promotion for an existing plan
   a. Promotion can be limited in two ways
   i. By the number of users to get the promotion (for example: 500 users)
   ii. By a time period (for example: 22th May 2022 to 24th May 2022)
   b. Assume that promotion can only affect benefitPercentage for a given plan

Code I have written for Plan Model

```
class Plan(models.Model):
    planID = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    planName = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    amountOptions = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=AMOUNT_CHOICES, default="cash")
    tenureOptions = models.IntegerField(default=1, choices=TENURE_CHOICES)
    benefitPercentage = models.FloatField(default=0)
    benefitType = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=BENIFIT, default="cashback")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.planName
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic model would look something like this, I haven't filled out the field specifics but this wouldn't be very complicated to do. Your business logic would be tested whenever someone tries to apply a promotion to a plan - I would suggest adding a method to the Plan model that checks for current  valid promotions, your promotion class can then have a method called is_valid which checks the dates and how many users have already used it etc. you would want another model that tracks how many promotions have been applied (probably just tracking the code/name/ID somewhere). If there is a valid promotion then take that benefit rate instead of the plan rate, again probably a method on the Plan class.

```
class Promotion(models.Model):
   promotion_name = models.CharField(...
   valid_from = models.DateField(...
   valid_to = models.DateField(...
   permitted_users = models.IntegerField(...
   benefit_rate = models.IntegerField(...

   def is_valid(self):
      # check dates and usage and return True if ok
      return False
```